# ACF Repeater Loop with Bootstrap Rows Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to output 3 posts in a row, then move onto the next row if there is more than 3. If there is a number of posts that isn't a multiple of 3, it needs to close the row off. At the moment, content underneath this code is breaking depending on how many posts there are (the row isn't getting closed off as it should).

```
        <div class="choose-style">

            <h2>Choose a style</h2>

            <?php
                $f = 1;

                //Start loop
                $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'styles', 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => '6' ) );

                    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="image-grid-wrapper">

                    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

                            if ($f == 1) { ?>
                                <div class="row"> 
                            <?php } ?>

                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="image-grid-item">
                                    <?php
                                        $carousel = get_field('styles_slider');
                                        $first = $carousel[0]['image'];

                                        if ($first != NULL) {
                                            $image = $first['sizes']['medium'];
                                        } else {
                                            $image = get_template_directory_uri() . "/assets/img/placeholder.png";  
                                        }

                                    ?>
                                    <div class="image-wrapper">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <div class="image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image; ?>')">
                                            <div class="overlay">
                                                <div class="overlay-inner">
                                                    <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <?php if ($f == 3 ) { ?>
                                </div>                  
                            <?php $f = 1; continue; };          

                            $f++; ?>

                        <?php endwhile; endif;

                        if($f < 3) { ?>
                            </div><!--END OF POSTS -->
                        <?php }; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

                </div><!-- end image grid wrapper -->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <?php the_field('choose_style_text'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div><!-- end choose-style -->
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about this... change

```
if ($f == 1) { ?>
   <div class="row"> 
<?php } ?>
```

To (if $f is 1 or 4, 7, 10, etc start the row)

```
if ($f == 1 || ($f-1)%3 == 0) { ?>
   <div class="row"> 
 <?php } ?>
```

And change

```
<?php if ($f == 3 ) { ?>
   </div>                  
<?php $f = 1; continue; };
```

To (if $f is divisible by 3, close the row)

```
if ($f%3 === 0) { ?>
   </div> 
<?php } ?>
```